# ObjectMaterialized and SavingChanges events in Entity Framework 7?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

`ObjectMaterialized` and `SavingChanges` were two very useful events in previous versions of Entity Framework. Those events actually belonged to the underlying `ObjectContext` API, which no longer exists in Entity Framework 7.

So what are the corresponding entity lifecycle events in Entity Framework 7 that can be used for customized extensions?

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like there is anything yet - both of the following Github issues are on the Entity Framework 7 Backlog, so they're expected, but not before RTM:

- [Lifecycle Hooks](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/626)
- [Datastore Command Interception](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/1629)